# nested resource(relations) in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a database with tables `teams`, with fields `id` and `name`, and `players` with fields `id`, `team_id` and `name`. I want to create records in the `players` table AFTER I create a record in the `teams` table. so the logic is - 1) create team. 2) go to edit/update this team, and there will be button `add player` there i can add player, and this player automatically belongs to this team. lets say i create team named `Juventus`, then i go to edit `Juventus` and there add player named `alex` after i submit `alex` belongs to `Juventus` . the question is what is the best way to do this? my idea is make route like `teams/1/players` and also `teams/1/players/create` and so on... where 1 is `team_id` . how can i do this?

Comment: What does the route have to do with your database?

Comment: IMHO this way is better /player/create/?team=1